# Github actions: Can the effects of one job trigger another?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to define a workflow as follows, for a node.js repo:

- When new code is merged into master AND version in package.json is changed, create a new Github release for that version
- When a new Github release is created, publish package to NPM

What I hope to achieve is that in our most typical workflow (PR merged to master) a release s created and package is automatically uploaded to NPM but to also be able to trigger an upload to NPM directly from a feature branch (usually a pre-release version, 1.0.3-rc1) by manually creating a release from such branch.

I've set up two Github workflows, each with a single job.
The first:

```
name: Create release on new version merge
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
jobs:
  release-on-new-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Check for version change
        id: check
        uses: EndBug/version-check@v1
        with:
          file-url: ::before
          static-checking: localIsNew
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Log when changed
        if: steps.check.outputs.changed == 'true'
        run: 'echo "Version change found: ${{ steps.check.outputs.version }}"'
      - name: Create Release
        if: steps.check.outputs.changed == 'true'
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: v${{ steps.check.outputs.version }}
          release_name: v${{ steps.check.outputs.version }}...
```

The second:

```
name: Publish on new release

on:
  release:
    types: created

jobs:
  publish-on-release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.npm_token}}
```

Individually these workflows work as expected: When I merge some work onto master that changes the version number a release is created, and when I manually create a release it gets published to NPM. However I would also expect the release created as the effect of the first workflow to trigger the second flow and therefore when I merge a version change into master eventually automatically see it published to NPM. But to my amazement that does not happen. Is there some sort of mechanism that prevents the effects of one job to (indirectly) trigger another? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe this is because API requests in a workflow cannot trigger another workflow. Thus you need to create a personal-access-token and use that for the release-creation step. I am trying to confirm this though.

Comment: Yeah https://github.community/t/triggering-a-new-workflow-from-another-workflow/16250/29

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to explicitly mention the dependency of one job needed another job, using [`needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds).

You can see that approach illustrated with:

"[GitHub Actions: Dependent Jobs](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/github_actions_17_dependent_jobs.html)" from [**Edward Thomson**](https://www.edwardthomson.com/about/) (who is also [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson))

That would allow to define a third action which would need the first two, forcing them to be chained in their execution.

Comment: They are separate workflows, so defining a dependency between them is not possible. Also, I don't really want them to be directly dependent. The point is to also be able to trigger the second one (publish) by manually creating a release. What I don't get is why the effect of job 1 (creating a release) doesn't trigger job 2 (which is triggered by creating a release).